# Understand Sails Js & Vue.js dialog

Tags: session, vue.js, sails.js, jwt

I'm learning both Sails and Vue.js and making a full REST app to do that.

So far from now, I've made a multi-step sign-up page in Vue which is working fine and POST all needed informations in my different Controllers in Sails, it also creates the user.

Now, I'm working on my login page. Again, no problem to PUT informations in my Login Controller and I receive an OK (200) response which let me know the user is logged on my backend server.

Now, I would like to understand how I could keep the information the user is logged-in my server and let him access to private content on my front-end app -> securely. I have understood that Sails use Sessions (alias of cookies ?). Also in the common example on the web, people tend to use JWT which transmit a crypted JSON between the two environnement (and so desactivate the cookies ?).

So, could you please give me a semantic explanation on how I can make both app exchange securely and manage it in Vue Js. I just need some "track" to follow.

Comment: If you are talking about secure data exchange between client and the server, so simply use HTTPS. No?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already use HTTP requests thanks to Axios. I am talking about giving an access to private route/HTTP request on my Vue frontend app. How to handle the Sessions generated on my Sails backend app and verify it on each HTTP and route request to be sure that the user is logged in and has the permissions to.

Comment: Looks like you are talking about Policies - https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/policies. If so, I can try to give normal answer.

Comment: Thanks again - That is not exactly what I'm looking for. Policies are made for authorization on the backend server (before a controller action). My problem concerns only the frontend part, which I have made with Vue JS. I just don't understand what I should do after a user has logged in and my backend sent a cookie. How would the frontend "remember"/"know' the user is already logged in and has the permission to acces a specific page on the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

For those who like me are blocked at this initial step, I resolved my problem this way.

1) My *backend Sails* app generates a JWT (`token`) on each login.

2) My *frontend Vue* app stores that information thanks to **Vuex** and set the header of each request with an `Authorization` parameter composed of : `'Barear ' + token`.

3) All frontend resquests to any Sails controller are verified thanks to a Policy which compares the *token* in the header of the request with the one generated at the first step.

Now I just wonder if using built in sessions in Sails is relevant or not.